# Can memory with DDR3 1066 MHz run PC-10600

Tags: memory, ddr3

My laptop is [Asus k42jb](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks/Versatile_Performance/K42JB/). And the specification said that its DDR3 1066MHz. I intend to buy a memory with PC-10600. will this memory run on my laptop? it doesn't matter if it will be run on PC-8500 as long as it run on my laptop.

and also there is already 1 GB memory that came with the laptop. If i add the PC-10600 will it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it will work as all DDR3 RAMs are having the same slot size. Additionally PC10600 is a RAM with frequency of 1333Mhs. 
The only limitation you will have is that the memory frequency of both your RAMs will be fixed to the lower one (1066 Mhz). Otherwise, it will work with the existing memory as said.